# how to print magic matrix upto n square for a given number n

Tags: java, matrix, logic

I am trying to implement matrix logic in a program riddle. This is not a home work I am just trying to practice it on my own but could go further without guidance or approach.

The problem is suppose we have given number let's say n than a matrix should get generated upto n*n numbers with following pattern

ex: Number is 3

1 2 3

7 8 9

4 5 6

like wise if the the number is 4
than

1 2 3 4

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

5 6 7 8

for problem solving I used following logic but it could not give me expected output

```
public static void printPattern(int i){
    int num= i*i;
    int n=1;
    int[][] matrixArray = new int[i][i];

    for (int g=0;g<i ;g++ ){

        for (int j=0; j<i&& n<=num; j++,n++){
            System.out.println("i::"+i+"::j"+j+"number is :"+n);
            if (g!=0 &&g%2==0){
                System.out.println("g is "+g);
                matrixArray[g][j]=n;
            }
            else{
            matrixArray[g][j]=n;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int g=0;g<i ;g++ ) {

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrixArray[g][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much simpler approach. Just keep alternating between `top` and `bottom` rows within the main loop and you wouldn't have to use `if-else` constructs at all.

```
public static void printMatrix(int num) {
    int n = 1;
    int[][] matrix = new int[num][num];
    for (int top = 0, bottom = num - 1; top <= bottom; top++, bottom--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            matrix[top][i] = n++;
        }
        if (top == bottom) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            matrix[bottom][i] = n++;
        }
    }
    for (int[] arr : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Here the loop runs till the `top` crosses `bottom` i.e. when `top = bottom + 1` for **even** number of rows. For **odd** number of rows, the loop `break`s out when `top = bottom` **after** filling that row once.

***Output :*** *printMatrix(4); // even*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

***Output :*** *printMatrix(5); // odd*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in your inner for loop to the following

```
if (g % 2 == 1) { // Handle rows with odd index (second, fourth ...)
    matrixArray[i - (g + 1) / 2][j] = n;
} else { // First, third ... rows
    matrixArray[g / 2][j] = n;
}
```

[See it run live](http://ideone.com/v4MXg3)